# Will VPC Support for Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domains Configure Using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation

I am configuring AWS Elastic Search Cluster using cloudformation but i am unable to use VPC enable cluster using CFN template so my question is this is possible configuration if yes then can someone provided me link for that.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not supported; support will come soon according to the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the info